# How does this Python function work?

Tags: python, function

I'm going through an MIT open courseware class right now for Python, and I'm not understanding how this function is returning 9.

```
def a(x):
   '''
   x: int or float.
   '''
   return x + 1

a(a(a(6)))
```

The above returns 9. I've went through it step by step using pythontutor (Visualize Python) and I'm still not understanding.

I understand the function. It has a name of a, and takes one argument, x. If I did a(6) I'd expect 7 to be returned. It's the **a(a(a(6)))** that confuses me - all of the a's and parentheses.

How is this working? Maybe a step by step sequence of what each **a** means, etc.

Based from your replies, is this what you mean?

[image: image describing the process]

Comment: `a(6)` is `7`, so `a(a(6))` is `a(7)`.

Comment: The innermost function is executed first. It returns 7. Then then next layer will receive 7 as its argument and return 8. etc. Python's order of operation is pretty much the same as in standard mathematical expressions.

Comment: What your are looking for is called recursion. That occurs when a function is calling itself ...

Comment: @mahatmanich This is _not_ recursion.

Comment: @Dyz ah ok the call is just upon itself and recursion is not included in the function itself ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see it as

```
x = a(6) # returns 7
y = a(x) # returns 8
z = a(y) # returns 9
```

In both cases, the result of the function is used für the next function call, and this result for the next again.

The first function call turns 6 into 7, the second 7 into 8 and the third and last turns 8 into 9.

The image included in your question exactly describes this.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You guys are the best